# Pooling SHAP values from multiple imputed data

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, multiple-imputation, pooling, shapley-value

I have multiple imputed data and will be conducting an identical lightGBM model with the same input features in each of the imputed datasets. My aim is to calculate SHAP values (SHapley Additive exPlanations) for each of the features in the model, but that leaves me with a different set of SHAP values for each model conducted in each of the imputed datasets. Could someone please point me in the direction of the correct or justifiable way to pool SHAP values for the same features that are calculated with multiple imputed datasets?

Comment: I would just take an average, and make a note of the spread.  The multiple shap values may derive as much or more variation from the different lightGBM fits as from the multiple imputations.  Correlated features will tend to have one picked as important by LGBM, and traditional "interventional"/"true-to-model" shap values will follow that; and which feature from a cluster of correlated features gets selected to play the biggest role may change across runs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ben. If the SHAP values "may derive as much or more variation from the different lightGBM fits as from the multiple imputations", then I'm a little worried about getting skewed values from a simple average. Perhaps there is a way to take into account the within and between imputation variation of the SHAP values when pooling?